# How do i get information about foreign keys in SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

The sqlite_master table seems to lack information. How can i get some extra information about my tables like constraint information etc.
Any examples? Or is there some usefull library out there that i`ve never heard off?

Comment: Why do you need to?  That information should be in your documentation, you shouldn't need to query the database for it.

Comment: i want to open any sqlite database from my phone,  get a list of all the foreign keys from the database , then check if referential integrity can be enforced , if not show the user all the dangling pointers .

Comment: This is my project , to do a database manager of sorts

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
PRAGMA foreign_key_list(table);
```

which returns the foreign keys for a table.

Then, you can use

```
PRAGMA foreign_key_check; 
PRAGMA foreign_key_check(table);
```

to list the violations, instead of doing it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The **sql** column of **sqlite_master** contains the **SQL** used to create  tables and thus includes foreign key information.

```
SELECT tbl_name,sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE sql LIKE('%REFERENCES%')
```

Would locate the rows for tables with foreign keys.

- `REFERENCES`, rather than `FOREIGN`, will include `FOREIGN KEY`s defined at the column level (as column-constraints), which only uses the foreign-key clause and as such does not include `FOREIGN KEY`.

---

However, `PRAGMA foreign_key_list(????)`, where `????` is the name of the table to inspect, provides the information in a more usable format (as per example below).

e.g. extracting from **sqlite_master** could result in (line breaks added) :-

```
CREATE TABLE Match(id_Match INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    id_Court INTEGER REFERENCES Court(id_Court), 
    id_Player INTEGER REFERENCES Player(id_Player), 
    id_Player1 INTEGER REFERENCES Player(id_Player))
```

whilst using `PRAGMA foreign_key_list(Match)` results in :-

[image]