# Is there a way to tell if a column is a foreign key?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have an sqlite database file and nothing else.  Is there a way to tell from the file, in python, what all the foreign key columns are in all the tables.  Or is there a way to tell if a given column is a foreign key?  I would also want to know where they point.

Comment: Maybe something in  https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html , or the scheme table https://sqlite.org/schematab.html

Comment: I couldn't find this before but here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508140/how-do-i-get-information-about-foreign-keys-in-sqlite

Comment: Cool. If it sufficiently answers the question, consider voting to close as a duplicate.